# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many doenst work with include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include

I am trying to drop same Languages from User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, uniq: true
end
```

But when i try to do

```
    lang = Language.where(id: params[:user][:lang_1])
    @user.languages << lang

    logger.debug(@user.languages.include? Language.where(id: params[:user][:lang_1]))
```

`include?` always returns false, even when `@user.languages` really contains `Language.where(id: params[:user][:lang_1])`. How fix `include?` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save `@user` to get new language stored for the user

```
    lang = Language.where(id: params[:user][:lang_1])
    @user.languages << lang
    @user.save!

    logger.debug(@user.languages.include?(lang))
```

Comment: I didnt expect answer so fast. :) Thank you, .save helped.